Why do some philosophers reject modal realism?
To me, modal realism seems particularly parsimonious - it assumes that if our world can exist, then any world that could exist does exist in "total reality", if only because to say "only our world exists" would require additional boundary conditions that somehow exclude all other worlds as being able to exist. These are extra elements in a theory that we cannot say exist, whereas I know at least one world exists.
I know others will say "you are positing all these other universes that we don't know exist". True - but we get a lot of nice explanatory power from that assumption and it doesn't presuppose entities that we don't know exist (worlds/universes) - only that we cannot think of any mechanism by which other worlds cannot exist.
For example, with modal realism, we can provide an objective and deterministic basis for probability/randomness.
Anyway, was wondering what the main arguments are against modal realism given all its strengths.

"some modern philosophers" is quite vague. The SEP article you cite continues to summarize rejections and Lewis' response. Similarly Wikipedia lists some criticisms. But each seems to complex and detailed to write a comprehensive answer. If you would focus more on one criticism, an answer would be easier.

"For example, with modal realism, we can provide an objective and deterministic basis for probability/randomness." This could require some development, because it's hard to see how modal realism helps on this front, or how randomness cannot be conceived under non-modal realism.

This site on reddit seems to have a reasonably grounded response: https://www.reddit.com/r/askphilosophy/comments/gngjh8/modal_realism_are_there_any_strong_arguments/

IS it more parsimonious? A good Bayesian test of parsimony is minimum description length (MDL). We have our observations - taken entirely from the universe we right now inhabit - and we wish to find a computer program of minimum length that outputs them exactly.
Can this computer program be made shorter if it is written with the assumption that other "possible worlds" exist?
First of all, all that matters is the length in bits required to output observations in the current world. We don't care about any other worlds except to the extent that they are useful assumptions to output the observations.
Perhaps the computer program could generate an array of worlds according to some universal rules, and then select the array entry that matches the observations. This probably wouldn't be all possible worlds, though; just ones following certain rules that are convenient to generate the observations. For example, the program could generate worlds from the many-worlds interpretation of quantum physics, and then select our own "branch." That would be reasonable. All these worlds would share the same laws of physics, though, so I'm not sure this would meet your criterion of all possible worlds.

would require additional boundary conditions that somehow exclude all other worlds as being able to exist.

You need to add those boundary conditions anyway, because your MDL program needs to exclude all the other worlds and only select the one that generates the exact observations in question.

For example, with modal realism, we can provide an objective and deterministic basis for probability/randomness.

No you can't. Are you imagining that each possible world would have an associated number, indicating the probability of that world? But these numbers would not match the Bayesian credences of any particular agent in any particular world. Probability is fundamentally a tool that agents can use to reason about effective actions, and probability depends on the agent. It quantifies what the agent doesn't know. "Objective" probabilities are problematic.
But what I'd say is the biggest problem with modal realism (and modal logic in general) is the question of exactly which worlds are "possible." Is any world I can describe possible? Is the Harry Potter universe possible? Where are the limits? It's reasonable (as described above with MDL and MWI) to suppose a multiverse with certain laws of physics, but not all fictional worlds with all imaginable laws of physics.
There are philosophers, such as David Lewis, who have given their interpretation of what the set of possible worlds ought to be. Lewis thinks it should be the set of all spatiotemporal arrangements of "objects" (although this is still a bit vague and makes some assumptions about the structure of spatetime). But Lewis is not the only one with ideas on what the set of possible worlds should be, so the question remains, why should it be that set, and not some other one?
Anyway, to summarize, it's not more parsimonious to be a modal realist about the set of possible worlds usually discussed by modal logicians, because that set of worlds is "too big"; it doesn't help reduce the MDL because it doesn't constrain the possible outputs enough (or at all). But it could be more parsimonious to be a modal realist about a restricted multiverse consistent with certain equations of physics, as in the MWI of quantum physics.

This reply is at risk of being a discussion rather than an answer. Yet this site is not great for back-and-forth argumentation about a theory.

@KristianBerry Don't give me the "courtier's reply." It's a problem they talk about, but it's still the biggest problem. If you claim it's not a problem, then go ahead and tell me: what is the set of possible worlds? There is no answer you can give. "Possible" more properly refers to things an agent cognitively can't rule out, but modal logic treats it as if it were objective, just the same as the fallacy of treating probabilities as objective when they are actually cognitive tools of an agent.

@KristianBerry Yeah, that really sounds like a clear and unambiguous statement of what the set of possible worlds is.

@KristianBerry Yeah they're beyond it, so they don't need to answer, and there's no such thing as being clear anyway. Good point.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Re: "No you can't. Are you imagining that each possible world would have an associated number, indicating the probability of that world?"
The formalization of probability theory (in math) quite literally quantifies over a set of possible worlds, in which each possibility "really exists" regardless of how the random variables are realized. My impression is that this is what OP was referring to, when they said we can provide an objective and deterministic basis for randomness. It's wholly possible to formalize probability theory without this concession, but that's extremely unpopular.

(cont.) In regards to your question: yes, each possible world really would have an associated number, indicating the probability of that world. For continuous random variables, the probability of any individual possible world is usually zero (which is not the same as "impossible"). Measure/probability theorists are usually more interested in the probability of events rather than the probability of individual worlds. Also, the reason alternative formalizations of probability theory are so unpopular is precisely because they are extremely complicated, and take far more effort to describe.

@JadeVanadium But, what single, objective, universal probability distribution do you assign to the set of possible worlds? Probability is relative to an individual; it quantifies the individual's lack of knowledge. If an individual knows more, the probabilities for that individual would be different.

@causative That criticism seems aimed at probability theory in general, rather than any specific formalization of it, and I ought not to address it since probability isn't a critical part of my personal ontology. The fact remains: If you're already using probability theory, it's far easier to formalize using a form of modal realism. It's what you'll find in any graduate-level textbook. Annika (OOP) seems to be very active on MathSE, so they're likely familiar with that conventional formalization, and that's likely what they meant by "we can provide an objective ... basis for probability"

@JadeVanadium If you're encoding probabilities directly in the set of possible worlds, this is not compatible with the fact that probabilities depend on the individual.

@causative You can just use conditional probability. If you want to learn how mathematicians formalize & use probability theory, I suggest Billingsley: Probability and Measure. It's a good introductory text.

@JadeVanadium I have a math degree with a concentration in statistics.

@causative In that case, you already understand my objection. Any argument of the form "probability theory is incoherent under modal realism" is obviously false, since the only common formalization of probability theory falls precisely under modal realism. I'd remove my downvote if such an error is corrected, and won't clarify my objection any further.

@JadeVanadium Your objection is wrong. You can't just use conditional probability because each world has more than one agent living in it. What would you condition on? To use conditional probability you'd have to associate each agent in a given world with its own, different, set of possible worlds, e.g. if you have P(A|B) then B would be a set of worlds that needs to be different for each agent. This doesn't really square with the assumptions of model theory. In probability theory, each agent normally would get its own probability space; they don't all share the same one.
